# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyproj._network'

Tags: spyder, modulenotfounderror, pyproj

I am trying to run Python Code on Spyder for scientific computing. I use geometric information from shape files using geopandas. Installing geopandas was already difficult but I finally managed. However now I have another issue, that a module called 'pyproj._network' is not found.
I checked and the module is there and was also added to the path using the PYTHONPATH manager of Spyder.
Now I dont know anymore- any help very much appreciated!
Thanks!

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyproj._network'

---

Entering post mortem debugging...

---

> c:\users\stefano-work\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pyproj\network.py(10)()
> 8 import certifi
> 9
> ---> 10 from pyproj._network import (  # noqa: F401
> 11     _set_ca_bundle_path,
> 12     is_network_enabled,

`